# Error de un servo en arduino

Tags: arduino

Hola quisiera saber porque en el programa que dejara a continuacion el servo 8 y nueve no funcionan correctamente

```
#include<Servo.h> 
Servo servo_10; 
Servo servo_9; 
Servo servo_8; 
int grad_x = 90; 
int grad_y = 90; 
int a; 
int b; 

void setup() {  
    pinMode(2,INPUT_PULLUP);   
    servo_10.attach(10);   
    servo_9.attach(9);  
    servo_8.attach(8); 
} 

void loop() {   
    a = analogRead(A1);   
    b = analogRead(A0);   

    if (digitalRead(2)==0){
      servo_10.write(0);   
    }else{
      servo_10.write(40);   
    }   

    if (a > 700 && a < 180){
     grad_x++;   
    }   
    if (a < 300 && a > 0){
     grad_x--;   
    }   
    if (b > 700 && b < 180){
     grad_y++;   
    }   
    if (b <  300 && b > 0){
     grad_y--;   
    }   
    servo_9.write(grad_y);   
    servo_8.write(grad_x); 
}
```